# Cannot access my asp.net pages through Mono

Tags: asp.net, macos, mono

I'm trying to set up a local asp.net server on OSX using mono and I feel like I've followed all the steps layed out in the documentation but I getting thrown [this error](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s113/sh/bc8fe32c-33c8-49a4-958f-1df0fe8dcafd/cfc0f53172bcae66a4a9d1637d1788f6/deep/0/Error-404.png) when I go to view my test page on the local host.

When I attempt to route my web browser straight to the test file I get [the source code](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s113/sh/e6ecfaac-ce4f-4b59-9c73-c61f5930e4b8/d04bdb9d088f03d65e1f81cede3aed78/deep/0/localhost-8080-index.asp.png) so I know that part is there but it doesn't want to show it to me.

What's the issue here?

Comment: "I feel like I've followed all the steps" That's the interesting part, as the steps are rather complicated, http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_ASP.NET_Applications

Comment: Hmm... well that guide is for Linux and Windows. Yes it's complex and I'm sure I'm missing something but I need help knowing what it is I'm missing.

Comment: from the image i see your page is .asp and not .aspx, why?

Comment: We've always had our pages in .asp. Not sure why, I did change it to test and got an [error](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s113/sh/3a692930-d5c1-4422-bab8-a3bc994f9360/500e5c461694e6b3254b9afb859d66c5/deep/0/Error-404.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the file extension `.asp` instead of `.aspx`. Asp.net will not touch it when looking for which file to show (when surfing to `/`), or process the content when browsing directly to it.

Comment: Hmm.. Alright I changed the filetypes to .aspx and all the includes as well and it changed something but I'm still getting an [error](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s113/sh/3a692930-d5c1-4422-bab8-a3bc994f9360/500e5c461694e6b3254b9afb859d66c5/deep/0/Error-404.png).

Comment: I removed all the includes and consolidated them into the main file just to see if I could get it working. Now I'm getting a completely different[error](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s113/sh/8a0d5238-d4c9-482f-b25a-7a8d07099ddd/2d0153cf5e82ab2bb5746807bc5729fd/deep/0/Compilation-Error-and-osx---Cannot-access-my-asp.net-pages-through-Mono---Stack-Overflow.png).

Comment: Your latest error indicates an issue with the compilation, somelike like dll-files built with other source files than those present. Does the error go away if you rebuild everything?

Comment: I just ran the server to get it to serve the most [basic file I could think of](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s113/sh/adfb5cad-8326-41da-ab07-3a15b8aafd7b/1500bf790fe347c04f3b70255aa813eb/deep/0/index.aspx.png) with no files being referenced and I got the exact same error.

Comment: I would look into your webserver configuration, it may be something as it pointing to another wwwroot. The error messages mentions .NET 2.0, do you perhaps intend to use .NET 4.0 (or later)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem here lies on HTTP header side.
Your browser shows your html source as if it was an editor.
This happens when you have your **Content-Type** header missing, malformed or set to 'text/plain'.

For your page to show correctly you must have:

> Content-Type: text/html

How it is set is easy to find - get a Firefox browser with Firebug plugin - when activated go to 'net' tab to check your request responces.

Comment: That seems to be appearing just fine: [Screen](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s113/sh/a861c4aa-3a00-41ab-aba0-5962baac4382/81721edeef619304a8905a351fc1eeb8/deep/0/Compilation-Error-and-osx---Cannot-access-my-asp.net-pages-through-Mono---Stack-Overflow.png)